# Can Jetpack Compose Icon load a Selector XML?

Tags: android, imageview, android-jetpack-compose, android-selector

I have an imageview, which uses Selector

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_back_hand_24_selector"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Where the selector is choosing between 2 vector drawable images depending on the state

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_back_hand_24" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_outline_back_hand_24" />
</selector>
```

This is very handy, that we can swap the image, by programmatically set the state to True or False

```
theImageView.setOnClickListener {
    this.isSelected = !this.isSelected
}
```

However, if I put it on the Jetpack Compose `Icon` as below

```
Icon(painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_back_hand_24), contentDescription = "")
```

It crashes stating

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only VectorDrawables and rasterized asset types are supported ex. PNG, JPG
```

Is there no way for Jetpack Compose Icon to load a Selector XML?

Comment: Compose cannot do that by default now, you can try accompanist drawable painter: https://github.com/google/accompanist/tree/main/drawablepainter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use something different to change how components appear in different states.

For example:

```
var selected by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val drawableResource = if (selected) R.drawable.xxx else R.drawable.xxx

Image(
    painter = painterResource(id = drawableResource),
    contentDescription = "contentDescription",
    modifier = Modifier.clickable { selected = !selected }
)
```

Comment: NIce, that's what I figure... move the selector logic to Jetpack Compose ourselves.